# distributed.worker - WARNING - Heartbeat to scheduler failed

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm running long running dask.delayed() jobs (that uses subprocess to run external binaries to process large files), and get cancelled Futures due to all workers losing their scheduler communication:

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - Heartbeat to scheduler failed
```

The scheduler says:

```
distributed.core - INFO - Event loop was unresponsive in Scheduler for 3.99s.  
This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data.
This can cause timeouts and instability.
```

Why does this happen, and how do I work around it/fix it? From my understanding, the scheduler doesn't run any of my python code itself...

Comment: I got this as well from a worker that runs a cython/c task.

Answer (score 2):

As the warning mentions, the main thread of the worker wasn't able to do anything for a while.  This is often caused by calling compiled functions that hold onto the GIL.  They grab the GIL and then disappear into compiled code for a while, not letting any other Python code (like heartbeat messages) run.

The right way to solve this problem is to have your compiled code release the GIL.  If you have control over this code then it is usually an easy fix in Cython and now, I think, default in cffi.  If you're just calling `subprocess` then I don't have a good explanation for this.  That should not hold onto the GIL.